# Did I calculate this voltage correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, voltage

I have just started to learn physics.
Please forgive me if I am completely wrong or something, I have just turned 14 haha.

---

I am trying to learn about how to work out voltage for my year 10 exams.
Here's what I have so far:

[image]

I got such a large value of 30000V so I think I might have made a mistake somewhere.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your multiplication.

$$
(9 \times 10^{9})(20 \times 10^{-9}) \neq 90\times20
$$
$$
(9 \times 10^{9})(20 \times 10^{-9}) = (9\times20)\times10^{0} = 9\times20 =180
$$

This means that your answer is off by a factor of 10. Without the error your answer should be 3kV.

Comment: Why the down vote?  This answer is correct. (up-voted to cancel the down vote)